# Is this possible to get Paid app purchase receipt from Google Play store?

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-console

We are working on a Xamarin project that needs to get the date of purchase of a Paid App that was posted in Android Playstore. I can see iOS providing the direct API for validating the receipt.
FYI, I'm not looking for an In-app purchase receipt. I'm looking for an initial paid app purchase/download receipt.

Is there any default API to get app purchase details?

Answer (score 0):

This code will return the first install (purchased time)

```java
context.getPackageManager()
                   .getPackageInfo("com.some.package.name", 0)
                   .firstInstallTime;
```

[documentation source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo#firstInstallTime)

Comment: App can be purchased before installing.

Comment: @Jabbar, Thanks for the response. Is it possible to track the User? So that we can allow him to install on multiple devices to use our application with the same id etc.,